# Azure AD B2C Localize forced password reset

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using this sample: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions_ForcePasswordReset.xml

In **line 117** the default value for "userMsg" is defined as '**Your password has expired, please change to a new password.**'

I am trying to localize this string but so far I have no clue where to specify it or what StringId/ElementId I should be using inside my LocalizedResources-Object.

Already tried to add this to my Localization:

```
<LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_subject"
      >Contoso account email verification code</LocalizedString
    >
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_message"
      >Thanks for verifying your account!</LocalizedString
    >
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_code"
      >Your code is</LocalizedString
    >
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_signature"
      >Sincerely</LocalizedString
    >
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
<LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.es">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_subject"
      >Código de verificación del correo electrónico de la cuenta de Contoso</LocalizedString
    >
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_message"
      >Gracias por comprobar la cuenta de
    </LocalizedString>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_code"
      >Su código es</LocalizedString
    >
    <LocalizedString ElementType="GetLocalizedStringsTransformationClaimType" StringId="email_signature"
      >Atentamente</LocalizedString
    >
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

Please give me some advice ❤️

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-or-sign-in-error-messages. `UserMessageIfPasswordExpired`, and should be in `api.signuporsignin` content definition. Your password can’t be expired on the sign up page (that’s what your code is referring to customise).

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to reset the force password while user Signing to the application***

> Note: Force password expired should be in sign_in_page, not signup process.

*Kindly modify the  **Policy ID**  &  **PublicPolicyUri**  according to your domain and upload the same xml file to your B2C Tenant. *

**TrustFrameworkExtensions_ForcePasswordReset.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="Yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_ForcePasswordReset" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_ForcePasswordReset">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>ThejeshInfotechB2c.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="forceChangePasswordNextLogin">
        <DisplayName>forceChangePasswordNextLogin</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Directory property, Whether the user password has expired</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="continueOnPasswordExpiration">
        <DisplayName>continueOnPasswordExpiration</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>continue ests non-interactive upon password expiration</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="samePassword">
        <DisplayName>samePassword</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Whether user enters the same password</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="userMsg">
        <DisplayName></DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>A claim responsible for holding user messages</AdminHelpText>
        <UserInputType>Paragraph</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <!--Compare the old and new password-->
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CompareOldAndNewPassword" TransformationMethod="CompareClaims">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="EQUAL" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="samePassword" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <!--Assert whether the old and new passwords are same, and return the UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual error message-->
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="ThrowErrorWhenPassowrdIsSame" TransformationMethod="AssertBooleanClaimIsEqualToValue">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="samePassword" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="valueToCompareTo" DataType="boolean" Value="false" />
        </InputParameters>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Continue if the password is expired  -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="continueOnPasswordExpiration" DefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Indicates whether user needs to reset the password.
            If the value of this claim is true, other claims aren't return-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextLogin" PartnerClaimType="passwordExpired" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!--Assert whether the new password is different than the old one. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ThrowErrorWhenPassowrdIsSame">
          <DisplayName>Assert New Password is different</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="samePassword" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CompareOldAndNewPassword" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="ThrowErrorWhenPassowrdIsSame" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        </TechnicalProfile>

      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Bubble up the forceChangePasswordNextLogin claim (return by the login-NonInteractive) to the user journey-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextLogin" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Self Asserted</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Password reset-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword">
          <DisplayName>Password Expired</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationBooleanValueIsNotEqual">Please enter a different password</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userMsg" DefaultValue="Your password has expired, please change to a new password." />
          </InputClaims>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userMsg" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </DisplayClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <!-- 1) validate the old password. 2) Assert whether the new password is different than the old one.
                 3) get the user object ID 4) persist the new password to the directory, and reset the force reset password next logon. -->
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ThrowErrorWhenPassowrdIsSame" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId-ResetNextLogin" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Read user objectId by signInName-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!--Save the new password to the directory-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId-ResetNextLogin">
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextLogin" PartnerClaimType="passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextLogin" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>


  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <!-- Skip this step if change password is required. -->
              <Value>forceChangePasswordNextLogin</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>forceChangePasswordNextLogin</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <!--Force password reset upon password expiration-->
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForcePasswordResetUponPasswordExpiration" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ForcePasswordReset-ExpiredPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- For social IDP authentication, attempt to find the user account in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>localAccountAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

**SignUp_SignIn_ForcePasswordReset.xml:**

**Modify the Policy ID & PublicPolicyUri in SignUp_SignIn_ForcePasswordReset.xml page with your Tenant name and upload the same to your B2C Tenant.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="Tenantname.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_ForcePasswordReset" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://Tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_ForcePasswordReset">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>ThejeshInfotechB2c.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_ForcePasswordReset</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn_Custom" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="forceChangePasswordNextLogin" PartnerClaimType="passwordExpired" DefaultValue="false" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

***Once upload the both the XML files, Test the result.***

**Azure AD B2C > Identity Experience Framework > B2C_1A_DEMO_SIGNUP_SIGNIN_FORCEPASSWORDRESET**

[image]

Once you enter the  **username**  and  **password**, It will redirect to force password page to reset your password.

[image]

Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/force-password-reset?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#force-password-reset-on-next-login